# Memory leak and valgrind errors in this small for loop?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, valgrind

I'm having trouble with this small part of the code that generates errors in valgrind. When I comment the code and run valgrind, I dont get any memory leak or error so this loop should be the cause:

```
///Print the top users
    const char* str;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (FinalArray[i].Score == -1) {
            break;
        }

        int id = UserGetID(user);
        char* name = UserGetName(user);
        int finalID = UserGetID(FinalArray[i].user);
        char* finalName = UserGetName(FinalArray[i].user);

        assert(finalName!= NULL && name !=NULL);
        str = mtmSuggestFriends(id, name, finalID, finalName);

        if (str == NULL) {
            return MAIN_ALLOCATION_FAILED;
        }

//      fprintf(fileOutput, str);
    }
```

after this loop I simply return an enum stating success.

Here are the errors in Valgrind:

```
==8779== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==8779==    at 0x4037C2: UserGetName (in /u1/023/mtm/ex2/RUN/mtm_isocial)
==8779==    by 0x401FAC: SuggestFriends (in /u1/023/mtm/ex2/RUN/mtm_isocial)
==8779==    by 0x402E6D: executeUserCommand (in /u1/023/mtm/ex2/RUN/mtm_isocial)
==8779==    by 0x40281B: main (in /u1/023/mtm/ex2/RUN/mtm_isocial)
==8779== 
==8779== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==8779==    at 0x4037A0: UserGetID (in /u1/023/mtm/ex2/RUN/mtm_isocial)
==8779==    by 0x401FC8: SuggestFriends (in /u1/023/mtm/ex2/RUN/mtm_isocial)
==8779==    by 0x402E6D: executeUserCommand (in /u1/023/mtm/ex2/RUN/mtm_isocial)
==8779==    by 0x40281B: main (in /u1/023/mtm/ex2/RUN/mtm_isocial)
==8779== 
==8779== Invalid read of size 1
==8779==    at 0x403F1A: mtmSuggestFriends (in /u1/023/mtm/ex2/RUN/mtm_isocial)
==8779==    by 0x401FEE: SuggestFriends (in /u1/023/mtm/ex2/RUN/mtm_isocial)
==8779==    by 0x402E6D: executeUserCommand (in /u1/023/mtm/ex2/RUN/mtm_isocial)
==8779==    by 0x40281B: main (in /u1/023/mtm/ex2/RUN/mtm_isocial)
==8779==  Address 0x9848B4458BB44589 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==8779== 
==8779== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==8779==  General Protection Fault
==8779==    at 0x403F1A: mtmSuggestFriends (in /u1/023/mtm/ex2/RUN/mtm_isocial)
==8779==    by 0x401FEE: SuggestFriends (in /u1/023/mtm/ex2/RUN/mtm_isocial)
==8779==    by 0x402E6D: executeUserCommand (in /u1/023/mtm/ex2/RUN/mtm_isocial)
==8779==    by 0x40281B: main (in /u1/023/mtm/ex2/RUN/mtm_isocial)
==8779== 
==8779== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 4 from 1)
==8779== malloc/free: in use at exit: 1,250 bytes in 93 blocks.
==8779== malloc/free: 455 allocs, 362 frees, 10,081 bytes allocated.
==8779== For counts of detected errors, rerun with: -v
==8779== searching for pointers to 93 not-freed blocks.
==8779== checked 122,512 bytes.
==8779== 
==8779== LEAK SUMMARY:
==8779==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
==8779==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
==8779==    still reachable: 1,250 bytes in 93 blocks.
==8779==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks.
==8779== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==8779== To see them, rerun with: --show-reachable=yes
```

The function ToStringUser returns a malloc of const char*.. So I shouldnt worry about freeing it right?

Any idea why is this happening?

I tried to free the str with this code in the for but I keep getting the same errors and the same amount of memory leaks:

```
free((char*) str); OR free((void*) str);
```

Here is the struct of the User and the getID and getName:

```
struct User_t {
    char *Name;
    int ID;
    int Birth;
};
int UserGetID(User user) {
    return user->ID;
}
char* UserGetName(User user) {
    return user->Name;
}
```

Before the loop I initialize a new User with this:

```
User user = FindUserPointer(setUser, id);
```

The function used is this:

```
static User FindUserPointer(Set users, int ID) {
        assert(users!=NULL);
    User tmpUser = UserCreate("temp", ID, 99);
    if (tmpUser == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    SET_FOREACH(User,Itrator1,users) {
        if (UserCompare(tmpUser, Itrator1) == 0) {
            UserFree(tmpUser);
            return Itrator1;
        }
    }
    UserFree(tmpUser);
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: why wouldn't you worry about freeing it?

Comment: You should always worry about freeing memory.

Comment: What is `user` in the for loop? And the program segfaults in the `mtmSuggestFriends` function, so it might be useful to see that.

Comment: @msam even if I free it by casting str to void* or char*, I keep getting these errors and the 93 block of memory leak.

Comment: @dbaupp I create a user and get the pointer to that user at the start of this function (before the loop):  User user = FindUserPointer(setUser, id);. Regarding the mtmSuggestFriends, its in a object file and I dont have the code though its shouldnt be the cause of the problem cuz my friends had no problems using it.

Comment: @Philip How do I free a const..? Even when I free the strwith a cast I get the errors and memory leaks. Question updated

Comment: @Omar, The program has crashed. Your leak is another problem.

Comment: @Omar: By calling `free()` on it ;) Note that `free()` doesn't change the value of its argument, though it wouldn't matter anyway.

Comment: @Philip I get this error when freeing the str with no cast: "passing argument 1 of 'free' discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type"

Comment: @Omar, the program crashes (that's what `Invalid read of size 1` + `SIGSEGV` mean), you should fix that before you worry too much about `free`ing the memory.

Comment: @Omar: You're right. I looked it up, and the idiomatic solution is to not use `const` pointers to store the result of `malloc()`. It doesn't make sense anyway, since you're going to change (i.e. `free()`) the pointer afterwards.

Comment: @Philip The problem was something else. I was getting out of the array bounds. when I fixed that, I dont have errors nor memory leaks. I dont have to free the const.. its freed automatically I guess :). Thanks for the help to u and to all the others!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Valgrind isn't complaining about a leak - it's complaining that you're reading uninitialized memory and dereferencing an invalid pointer (the invalid pointer deref is crashing the program - at least under Valgrind).

We'd need to see `UserGetID()` and `UserGetName()` to have a hope of determining the bug in those (but that still might not be enough).

Based on your comment that `mtmSuggestFriends` is an object file that you don't have source for, my guess is that `UsetGetID()` and/or `UserGetName()` are passing invalid pointers to `mtmSuggestFriends`.

Comment: Question updated with the code. the mtmSuggestFriends is a function in an object file. it mallocs and returns a const char*. Its not the cause of the leak as many of my friends used it and had 0 leaks when using it.

Comment: I updated the for loop with the asserts (see code above) and its still working.

Comment: Now we know more, but don't know what the data passed in to `FindUserPointer()` looks like or what `SET_FOREACH()` is. But based on your description of `mtmSuggestFriends`, the problem might be that the heap is corrupted. Maybe `UserCreate()` has a bug (maybe not allocating enough memory to include the null terminator on the `Name` string?).

Comment: @Omar: step through the loop in a debugger.  I'll bet at some point `name` ends up being non-NULL but pointing to nonsense/invalid memory.  That will still pass the `assert()`, but won't make `mtmSuggestFriends()` happy.

Comment: I did that, and I found out that the test we got wanted more users than I actually had so I had to check the recieved user_count to the max number I could print (and not more).. So I was going out of the FinalArray bounds. I added a small if(..), and now I dont have memory leaks nor errors.Thanks for the help Michael.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are passing in an unassigned pointer `user`. Then your `SuggestFriends()` function called from `UserGetID()` is using this garbage pointer full of randomness as a real pointer which leads to the invalid read (`SEGV`)

You might find that setting "warnings as errors" (`-Werr` on gcc) would probably show you where you are doing unpredictable things.

Comment: I updated the code with the user assigning. I debbuged the code with eclipse and user is not NULL when reaching this error.

Comment: exactly, it is not NULL, it is a value that is not a valid pointer, probably from where valgrind complains about use of the uninitialized variable. You should ALWAYS initialize pointers to NULL.

Comment: I tried with this:  User user = NULL;
 user= FindUserPointer(setUser, id);
Is this what u mean? I still get the same error though. I also tried to return a COPY of the user in the FindUserPointer, but still the smae.

Answer (score 0):

```
struct User_t {
char *Name;
int ID;
int Birth;
};
int UserGetID(User user) {
    return user->ID;
}
```

...and where is `User` defined ?